# When to Grab Data From firebase in Swift (iOS dev)

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, structure

I'm currently creating an app which stores information in a database which the users device must have in order for certain parts of the app to respond differently.

My question is, when should I be calling for this data from firebase.

e.g.

In one part of my app, the app needs to know if the user is currently "connected" to another user. Currently, it checks this against the database as the user presses on the tab bar icon where this information needs to be known, which takes a couple seconds. (checked in the viewdidload() override func)

Should I be grabbing all data from the database before the first view controller is even displayed?

Is there a way to share this between all the view controllers? 
If I could load all data from the database into global variables on the device that all view controllers can see this would seem much easier, however i'm not sure if this is good practice.

What would you recommend?

My database structure: [image: database screenshot]

Basically, right now, when the user opens the app and logs in, I need the 'name' and 'family' of each user to be stored for use across the whole app globally across all classes and view controllers.

In terms of the list. when the user clicks the view controller where the list is, currently i'm just running code like this

```
  self.ref.child("familys").child(email.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")).child("list").observe(.value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in

        if DataSnapshot.hasChildren() == false{
            print("No list")
            return
        }

        self.tableList = DataSnapshot.value as! [String]

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }) { (Error) in
        print(Error)
    }
```

then it goes ahead and updates the list with the array 'tableList'.

This means the first time the user clicks to get to the shopping view, there is some delay before the list populates.

I'm not sure what the standard way is to go about grabbing data like this and when it should be done in a way which minimises data usage and database access frequency.

Comment: Short answer is yes, loading all your database data into app is extremely bad practice, and there are creative ways around it. I can't give you much more help without more info. Can you post the code of how you are checking for user connections, and the structure of your database?

Comment: @keverly Hi, I have added an image of my structure and the code i'm currently running. Any help would be appreciated, i'm very new to firebase and swift.

Comment: Please don't post images of textual structures. We can't use them in an answer without retyping and they are not searchable. Please post them as TEXT which can be obtained from the Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON. Then copy and paste a snippet into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. Although you may think you need all the data stored globally so you can access it from all view controllers, you don't. You can pass the data between viewControllers through segues. If you are making a tab based app, you just pull the data necessary for that ViewController in the `viewDidLoad()` (just like you are doing).

The name of the game is to structure your Firebase database so that when you pull data, you can **pull as little as possible to fill all the fields** in the View Controller. Since Firebase uses a JSON structure, there is **no shame in saving the same data twice in order to make a search faster**.

That being said, I think a `currentUser` global variable is useful in your case. Assuming you have a current user (one user logged in), I would just create a `User` class that mimics the Firebase  and instantiate one global variable called `currentUser`. Your currentUser object should contain enough information to go and pull anything you need for filling ViewControllers. For example if your `User` class has an email attribute, you can do:

```
self.ref.child("familys").child(currentUser.email.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")).child("list").observe(.value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in

    if DataSnapshot.hasChildren() == false{
        print("No list")
        return
    }

    self.tableList = DataSnapshot.value as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()


}) { (Error) in
    print(Error)
}
```

Global variables should be avoided when possible, but I think just reducing it to one global variable should be enough to get you going.

As for why you are getting a delay, I'm not sure. When you are pulling that little data, it should be extremely fast. If there really is a noticeable delay when pulling a list of 2 items, the issue might be elsewhere (network, simulator, etc.).

Comment: Encouraging to know i'm on the right tracks. I think creating a User class as you mentioned would be very useful in my situation, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Don't know if this is a good idea / bad practice. I have decided to store the essential user data in UserDefaults. I can then read and write to this as need be.

Comment: @Tizer1000 I would be careful with that. You might run into issues if the data in the database changes, but the UserDefaults data doesn't reflect those changes. If you write a change to the UserDefaults be sure you write that same change to Firebase.